# Change Event Report fee level filter so operator offers 'contains' rather than 'is one of'

Tags: civireport, participants

In the Participant Report there is a filter for Fee Level. The operator for this is either 'Is one of' or 'Is not one of'.

Is it possible to provide users with the option to search with the operator: 'contains'?

The behaviour appears to be the same in the normal participant report as well as in the Extended Report Extension's participant report.

The reason we want to do this is because we want to make participant lists for each of the various options in our price set.

We're on Civi 5.3.1 and Drupal 7.58. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Its possible to do it using [hook_civicrm_alterReportVar](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_alterReportVar/) hook. You can create your own filters using this hook.